# How to structure a client-server application with 'push' notifications

Tags: interop, notifications, rpc

**EDIT**: I forgot to include the prime candidate for web applications: JSON over HTTP/REST + Comet. It combines the best features of the others (below)

- [Persevere](http://persvr.org) basically bundles everything I need in a server
- The focus for Java and such is definitely on Comet *servers*, but it can't be too hard to use/write a client.

---

I'm embarking on an application with a server holding data, and clients executing operations which would affect this data, and thus require some sort of notification across all interested/subscribed clients.

The first client will probably be written in WPF, but we'll probably need to add clients written in other languages, e.g. a Java (Swing?) client, and possibly, a web client.

**The actual question**(s): What protocol should I use to implement this? How easy would it be to integrate with JS, Java and .NET (precisely, C#) clients?

I could use several interfaces/protocols, but it'd be easier overall to use one that is interoperable. Given that interoperability is important, I have researched a few options:

1. JSON-RPC

   - lightweight
   - supports notifications

     - The only .NET lib I could find, [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) doesn't support notifications
   - works well with JS

     - also true of XML-based stuff (and possibly, even binary protocols) BUT this would probably be more efficient, thanks to native support
2. Protobuf/Thrift

   - IDL makes it easy to spit out model classes in each language
   - doesn't seem to support notifications
   - Thrift comes with RPC out of the box, but protobufs don't
   - not sure about JS
3. XML-RPC

   - simple enough, but doesn't support notifications
4. SOAP: I'm not even sure about this one; I haven't grokked this yet.

   - seems rather complex
5. Message Queues/PubSub approach: Not strictly a protocol, but might be fitting

   - I hardly know anything about them, and got lost amongst the buzzwords`-- JMS? **MQ?
   - Perhaps combined with some RPC mechanism above, although that might not be strictly necessary, and possibly, overkill.

Other options are, of course, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I am partial to the pub/sub design you've suggested. I'd take a look at ZeroMQ. It has bindings to C#, Java, and many other platforms.

Bindings list: [http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:clr](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aclr)

I also found this conversation on the ZeroMQ dev listing that may answer some questions you have about multiple clients and ZeroMQ: http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2010-February/002146.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to easily publish events to clients across networks, you may wish to look at a the [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) standard. (Used by, amongst other things, Jabber and Google Talk.)

See the extension for [publish-subscribe](http://xmpp.org/protocols/pubsub/) functionality.

There are a number of [libraries in different languages including C#, Java and Javascript](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

As XMPP was mentioned, [SIP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3265.txt) has a similar functionality. [This](http://blog.tekelec.com/blog/bid/13023/SIP-and-Network-Data-Simplified-at-Last) might be more accessible for you.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Servoy](http://www.servoy.com) for this. It does automatic data broadcasting to web-clients and java-clients. I'm not sure if broadcasts can be sent to other platforms, you might be able to find an answer to that on their forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAP over HTTP to modify the data on the server and SOAP over SMTP to notify the subscribed clients.

**OR**

The server doesn't know anything about the subscription and the clients call the server by timeout to track updates they are interested in, using XML-RPC, SOAP (generated using WSDL), or simply HTTP GET if there is no need to pass back complex data on tracking.